# Typescript create type from multiple Unions for Record Key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Say I have:

```
type Eggs = "Scrambled" | "Fried" | "Poached"
type Drink = "Coffee" | "Orange Juice" | "Milk"
type Meat = "Bacon" | "Sausage" | "Steak"
```

I want to create a Record type that uses each combination of the values of those types as a key.  So

```
combinedType = Combined<Eggs, Drink, Meat> // How do I write Combined?
myRecord = Record<combinedType, number>

myObj: myRecord = {
"Scrambled_Coffee_Bacon": 2.3,
"Scrambled_Coffee_Sausage": 4.1,
.....

}
```

Ultimately the purpose is to ensure that myObj has a key/value pair for each combination of my types.

Comment: Looks like you just want [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w254zW); does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
type CombinedType = `${Eggs}_${Drink}_${Meat}`;
```